# Как исправить ошибку с libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

При запуске проекта java с libgdx выдает такую ошибку`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.` У меня Windows 10 64bit, Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: Драйвера на видеокарту как устанавливали? Автоматом через Центр обновления или с сайта производителя? Дело в том, что в первом случае вы получаете куцый драйвер, не поддерживающий OpenGL (ибо политика у Microsoft такая).

Comment: И да, укажите в вопросе операционную систему, её версию и разрядность, а также (желательно) версию вашей установки libgdx. Мой совет выше ориентирован на Windows.

Comment: Как посмотреть версию libgdx? Драйвера проверял и от Intel и через windows, пишет, что самые новые, которые могут быть.

Comment: Дело не в *версии* драйверов, а в том, *откуда они взяты*. Попробуйте удалить имеющийся драйвер (через список установленных программ, а затем черед Диспетчер устройств) и поставить вместо него **загодя** скачанный с https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ru (ну или https://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/support/detect.html).